# Object values to array, then replace, not a function?

Tags: javascript

So I am using Vue.js, which is not the problem I know, it is just something I'm doing wrong, and there is a reason I'm doing it this way, but I keep getting an error like its not an array.

Code:

```
methods: {
  async register() {
    this.errors = '';
    this.success = '';
    await RegisterService.insertUser(this.email, this.username, this.password, this.passwordTwo)
    .then(data =>  {
      if (data.data) {
        let v = Object.values(data.data);
        console.log(v);
        v = v.replace(/["[]]/g, '');
        this.errors = v;
      } else {
        this.success = `Registration Successful!`;
      }
    });
 }
}
```

So what I am getting is `v.replace` is not a function, I'm sure there is a simple reason for this and I am just whiffing at figuring it out.

Comment: `Object.values` returns an array, and there is no `replace` function for arrays.

Comment: `.replace` is a string function. `v` is not a string.

Comment: Oh, duh. I did a lot of googling but i didnt google the right question. Thanks.

Comment: just added `.toString()` to my first iteration of v.

Comment: Better if you explain exactly what you are wanting to do